# How to apply diff made by windows SVN on linux?

Tags: windows, linux, svn, diff, patch

On windows i created a multi-file diff with:

```
svn diff > mydiff.diff
```

Then moved it to linux machine (with the same version of the same repo, no changes). How cai i apply it? After executing

```
 patch -p0 < mydiff.diff
```

I get the following output:

```
patching file licstat/test/unittest/test_licstatactioncontainers.cpp
File licstat/test/unittest/test_licstatactioncontainers.cpp is not empty after patch, as expected
patching file licstat/test/unittest/test_licstatactions.cpp
Hunk #1 FAILED at 99.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file licstat/test/unittest/test_licstatactions.cpp.rej
can't find file to patch at input line 295
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: licstat/test/unittest/test_licenseserverusagemap.cpp
|===================================================================
|--- licstat/test/unittest/test_licenseserverusagemap.cpp       (revision 6767)
|+++ licstat/test/unittest/test_licenseserverusagemap.cpp       (working copy)
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

And the last line is prompt waiting for my action.

How should I create/apply the patch to make it work?

(edit) Now I see, that the file was missing and diff didn't create it. After creating the file manually I get errors like this:

```
patching file licstat/misc/generic/mysql/stored_procedures.sql
Hunk #1 FAILED at 220.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 245.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 622.
Hunk #4 FAILED at 661.
Hunk #5 FAILED at 810.
Hunk #6 FAILED at 822.
Hunk #7 FAILED at 868.
Hunk #8 FAILED at 999.
8 out of 8 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file licstat/misc/generic/mysql/stored_procedures.sql.rej
```

Answer (score 8):

Using "dos2unix" will not help if you have CR+LF line feed in your files on Linux.

This command should do the job with any combination of line feeds:

```
patch -p0 -l --binary < patch.diff
```

Answer (score 0):

That type of error can occur when the local file format is CRLF instead of LF when you're on a unix system.

patch tries to adapt the svn diff patch to the unix file format but trips up when the local files are in dos mode, which can happen when you share code bases between dos and unix environments.

What works for me is to first convert all the files about to be affected, for example:

```
grep ^+++ patchfile.patch | awk '{print $2}' | dos2unix
```

And then to apply the patch:

```
patch -p0 < patchfile.patch
```

Answer (score 0):

I quite regularly patch files between a windows and mac system and `patch` does seem to deal with the newlines correctly so I don't think that's the issue.  It looks like may you've deleted `test_licstatactioncontainers.cpp` and the first warning is about that.  The second appears to be complaining about not finding the file itself.

Could this be a filename case issue?  Windows is insensitive to filename case, but linux isn't.  Is the file actually called Test_LicenceServerUsageMap.cpp on linux perchance? Or the directory LicStat/Test ?

Comment: Yes, I removed the file (with svn), so it should be fine.
No, all directory/file names are lower-case.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the line endings in the patch file from DOS to Unix, using the `dos2unix` command.

Comment: This does not work if the underlying file has mixed line endings.